# Can't load jasmine-jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine-jquery

I added [jasmine-jquery-rails](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) gem to my rails project and added it to `spec.js.coffee`

```
#= require application
#= require jasmine-jquery
#= require_tree ./
```

In the browser I can see `jasmine-jquery` file along with other files (jquery, etc)

But this contruction

```
expect($('#image')).not.toBeVisible()
```

doesn't work because of error

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toBeVisible'
```

How to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've solved this by now.  jasmine-jquery is an extension to jasmine, but it's not the jasmine testing suite itself.  You'll also need the gem 'jasmine-rails'.